# mysql connection is slow sometimes on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb

background: it's 92G/20 CPU server with ubuntu 18.04

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.41-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

issue:

```
root@z:# time mysql -uroot -pXXX -e "select now()"
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2019-09-25 14:10:24 |
+---------------------+

real    0m22.267s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.006s
```

it takes 20 seconds to connect mysql.

**IMPORTANT: it's not always like that, it happens when we have more visits. we use php-fpm and not PERSISTENT=true for PDO since that's localhost connection, it uses sockets (so that's not TCP or network issue).**

usually it takes 0.0X seconds.

iostat:

```
    Linux 4.15.0-50-generic (fdb)   09/25/2019      _x86_64_        (20 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          48.22    0.00   17.26    0.79    3.08   30.65

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
loop0             0.00         0.00         0.00          8          0
sdb               0.09         0.27         2.20      24628     204340
sda             735.43      1740.89      5578.76  161421385  517281936
```

it seems alright.

mysql conf:

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

key_buffer_size         = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 32
wait_timeout            = 60
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 30000
max_connect_errors     = 3000
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
tmp_table_size          = 512M
max_heap_table_size     = 512M
table_open_cache        = 4096

performance_schema = on

innodb_buffer_pool_size=48G
innodb_log_file_size=6144M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=20
innodb_purge_threads=8
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

**we have skip-name-resolve so it's not DNS issue**

mysql status
sorry it's too large so I made it in gist: https://gist.github.com/fayland/97050f70cb258a41f1fa1bd3046df4d2

it would be great that someone can point us the direction to check. if you need any more info, we'll be glad to provide.

Thanks

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck https://gist.github.com/fayland/d0d637e65d7c283810f0cf53d68c8a95 probably that's not the right stats since the time now we don't have the issue. We'll see if we can capture when it happens. thanks

Comment: Thank you for posting requested info.  Analysis in process.  Due to out of town scheduled event, it may be my Wednesday before I post suggestions.  I am in UTC -6 hours, what is your time zone?

Comment: Yes, it's alright. We're considering to move the stuff to cluster like percona xtradb cluster since it still happens a lot recently (every hour actually). We're in UTC+8 China. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=256  # from 32 for default with v 10.0.38
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS to your SSD devices
read_buffer_size_256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 2,337,990
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 1,982,624
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5 # from 30 to reduce delays and reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 23,455
thread_concurrency=18  # from 10 to use more of your 20 cores
innodb_log_buffer_size=2G  # from 8M to support about 7 log minutes in RAM
```

There are more global variables to be tuned for your instance.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where you may download FREE Utility Scripts, and consider additional analysis services.

Comment: We'll try it and get back to you. thanks

Comment: @FaylandLam    Any comments you could share?  Positive/negative performance change?

Comment: a little better but the problem is not resolved. We're considering to move out of mariadb and try something else like percona server or postgresql. thanks